# Call Superclass method from overridden Subclass method

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, overriding

I'm sure this has a simple solution, but I'm new to Java and can't work it out.

I have a subclass Payroll that extends a superclass Pay, it contains an overridden method called 'calc_payroll'. From this method, I want to call the superclass method of the same name, and assign the output to a variable in the overriding method. My code is below

```
public class Payroll extends Pay
{
   public double calc_Payroll()
{
    double grossPay = super.calc_Payroll();
    double taxAmt = tax(grossPay);
    double netPay = grossPay - taxAmt;  

    System.out.println(grossPay);

    return netPay;
}


}
```

Below is the code from the calc_payroll method in the superclass

```
public double calc_Payroll()
{
    double otRate = rate * 1.77;
    double otHours = ttlHours - stHours;

    if(stHours == 0)
    {
        grossPay = otHours * rate;
    }

    else
    {
        grossPay = ((stHours * rate) + (otHours * otRate));
    }

    System.out.println(stHours + "//" + otHours + "//" + rate);//for testing

    return grossPay;
}
```

the superclass method functions without issue to calculate and return the gross pay when called from a different subclass, but when calling it from a method with the same name, the print line in the code above (that I have labelled for testing) displays zero's for all variables

Code for full 'Pay' class is below as requested

```
public class Pay
{
private double ttlHours;
private int stHours;
private double rate;
double grossPay = 0.0;
final double TAXL = 0.07;
final double TAXM = 0.1;
final double TAXH = 0.16;

public void SetHours(double a)
{
    ttlHours = a;
}

public void SetHoursStr(int a)
{
    stHours = a;
}

public void SetRate(double a)
{
    rate = a;
}

public double GetHours()
{
    return ttlHours;
}

public int GetStHours()
{
    return stHours;
}

public double GetRate()
{
    return rate;
}

public double taxRate()
{
    double taxRate = 0.0;

    if(grossPay <= 399.99)
    {
        taxRate = TAXL;
    }
    else if(grossPay <= 899.99)
    {
        taxRate = TAXM;         
    }
    else
    {
        taxRate = TAXH;
    }

    return taxRate;
}

public double tax(double grossPay)
{
    double ttlTax = 0.0;        

    if(grossPay < 400.00)
    {
        ttlTax += (grossPay * TAXL); 
    }

    else if(grossPay < 900.00)
    {
        ttlTax += (grossPay * TAXM);
    }

    else
    {
        ttlTax += (grossPay * TAXH);
    }

    return ttlTax;
}

public double calc_Payroll()
{
    double otRate = rate * 1.77;
    double otHours = ttlHours - stHours;

    if(stHours == 0)
    {
        grossPay = otHours * rate;
    }

    else
    {
        grossPay = ((stHours * rate) + (otHours * otRate));
    }

    System.out.println(stHours + "//" + otHours + "//" + rate);//for testing

    return grossPay;
}
}
```

The subclass Payroll contains no other code

Below is the code that accepts user input to assign values to the initialized variables

```
public class CalPayroll extends Pay
{
Payroll nPay = new Payroll();
Accept Read = new Accept(); 


public void AcceptPay()
{
    char select = '0';

    while(select != 'e' && select != 'E')
        {
            System.out.println("Payroll Computation \n");           
            System.out.print("Enter number of hours worked (00.0) <0 for Quick exit>: ");
            SetHours(Read.AcceptInputDouble());
            System.out.print("Enter first number of hours straight (integer or 0 to disable): ");
            SetHoursStr(Read.AcceptInputInt());
            System.out.print("Enter hourly rate of worker (00.00): ");
            SetRate(Read.AcceptInputDouble());
            Screen.ScrollScreen('=', 66, 1);
            Screen.ScrollScreen(1); 
            displayInfo();
            System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue");
            select = Read.AcceptInputChar();
        }
}

public void displayInfo()
{       
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    System.out.println("Gross pay is :" + currency.format(calc_Payroll()));
    System.out.println("Tax is :" + percent.format(taxRate()));
    System.out.println("Net pay is :" + currency.format(nPay.calc_Payroll()));      
    Screen.ScrollScreen(1);     
}


}
```

I'm confused!

Comment: Plz post your both full classes if possible, you might be not initialising those value while creating instance of class. By default all `int` gets `0`, and `float`, `double` gets `0.0`.

Comment: Can you expand on "when calling it from a method with the same name"...

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw OP just want to call a method inside a method that overrides it.

Comment: Which he has done and has mentioned it also works when he does that....

Comment: @jackjay - edited my post with full Pay class code

Answer (score 1):

Its clear from you code that `ttlHours, stHours and rate` are not initialised with some reasonable value. So when you just call `super.calc_Payroll()`, values like `0 or 0.0` are used as i explained in my comment. Its good to first set values of these variables before calling `super.calc_Payroll()`.

```
SetHours(23.4);  //some value

SetHoursStr(5);   //some value

SetRate(2.3);   //some value
```

Also you don't have constructor for `Pay` class, try making it and initialising all uninitialised variable in constructor or use `setter/getter` methods to set and get values.

Since your both classes extends `Pay` class, it creates the problem which you are facing. When you call `SetHours(Read.AcceptInputDouble())`, it set the variable inherited by `CalPayroll` from `Pay`, not the variables inherited by `Payroll` class. What you have to do is to set variables for `Payroll` instance as well as for current class as both extends `Pay`. Do the following replace your `while` loop as,

```
while(select != 'e' && select != 'E')
        {
            System.out.println("Payroll Computation \n");           
            System.out.print("Enter number of hours worked (00.0) <0 for Quick exit>: ");
            SetHours(Read.AcceptInputDouble());
            nPay.SetHours(GetHours());
            System.out.print("Enter first number of hours straight (integer or 0 to disable): ");
            SetHoursStr(Read.AcceptInputInt());
            nPay.SetHoursStr(GetStHours());
            System.out.print("Enter hourly rate of worker (00.00): ");
            SetRate(Read.AcceptInputDouble());
            nPay.SetRate(GetRate());
            Screen.ScrollScreen('=', 66, 1);
            Screen.ScrollScreen(1); 
            displayInfo();
            System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue");
            select = Read.AcceptInputChar();
        }
```

Comment: my bad, I thought you only wanted the code from the Pay class, I've edited the original post witht he code that accepts user input to assign values to the initialized variables

Comment: Thanks JackJay, I'll check it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete code.
It seems that for some reason your variables of super class method not getting assigned values properly. And they are initialized with their default values which is making everything 0. I'll be able to help better if you paste the complete class.